# How to create pdfs from rmarkdown in which an image can be selected and copied

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

The requirement is to create a pdf-report in which the user can select each plot, clicks on copy and can insert the image in e.g., powerpoint.
I used the shiny example app to create such an pdf-report with R:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html
(see code below)

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
        # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
        # can happen when deployed).
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
        file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params <- list(n = input$slider)

        # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
        # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
        # from the code in this app).
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Rmd:

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: pdf_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```

A plot of `params$n` random points.

```{r}
plot(rnorm(params$n), rnorm(params$n))
```
````

This app creates a report in which I can select only the inner part (blue selection) of the plot:
[image: report]
I would like to be able to select the whole plot area instead of only the inner part.

Comment: How is the code adapted? With the eg they have, I can copy the whole plot in the pdf download from here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/generating-reports.html

Comment: I just changed the export format from html to pdf. I added a screenshot to illustrate what I mean by inner part selection of the the plot.